# returning the value in a deck of cards after dealing a card

Tags: java

Trying to get my code to return the number of cards left in the deck after dealing a card. Running into some issues...I can't get it to work...here is what I have. I didn't put the dealer in because I haven't made it work here yet...so once I get it to work here then I will add it to my println in my dealer program.  Any help is appreciated...

```
public class Deckofcards
   {
      public static final int NCARDS = 52;

     public card[] deckOfCards;         // Contains all 52 cards
     public int currentCard;            // deal THIS card in deck           
     public int cardsused;              // How many cards have been dealt
     public int cardsLeft;

      public Deckofcards( )    // Constructor
      {
     deckOfCards = new card[ NCARDS ];

     int i = 0;

     for ( int suit = card.DIAMOND; suit <= card.SPADE; suit++ )
        for ( int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++ )
        deckOfCards[i++] = new card(suit, rank);
     cardsused = 0;
     currentCard = 0;
      }

       //shuffle(n): shuffle the deck

      public void shuffle(int n)
      {
     int i, j, k;

            for ( k = 0; k < n; k++ )
                {
                    i = (int) ( NCARDS * Math.random() );  // Pick 2 random cards
                    j = (int) ( NCARDS * Math.random() );  // in the deck

                        //swap these randomly picked cards

                    card tmp = deckOfCards[i];
                    deckOfCards[i] = deckOfCards[j];
                    deckOfCards[j] = tmp;;
                }

                        currentCard = 0;   // Reset current card to deal
      }


            public int cardsLeft()
            {
                cardsused = currentCard++;
                return 52-cardsused;
            }


      public card deal()
      {
      if ( currentCard < NCARDS  )
         {

            return ( deckOfCards[ currentCard++ ] );
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.println("Out of cards error");
            return (null);// Error;

         }  
      }


      public String toString()
      {
     String s = "";
     int k;

     k = 0;
     for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
     {
        for ( int j = 1; j <= 13; j++ )
        s += (deckOfCards[k++] + " ");

        s += "\n";
     }
     return ( s );
      }

   }
```

Here is what my output looks like.

```
    Ace of Diamonds,  2 of Diamonds,  3 of Diamonds,  4 of Diamonds,  5 of Diamonds,  6 of Diamonds,  7 of Diamonds,  8 of Diamonds,  9 of Diamonds,  10 of Diamonds,  Jack of Diamonds,  Queen of Diamonds,  King of Diamonds,  
Ace of Clubs,  2 of Clubs,  3 of Clubs,  4 of Clubs,  5 of Clubs,  6 of Clubs,  7 of Clubs,  8 of Clubs,  9 of Clubs,  10 of Clubs,  Jack of Clubs,  Queen of Clubs,  King of Clubs,  
Ace of Hearts,  2 of Hearts,  3 of Hearts,  4 of Hearts,  5 of Hearts,  6 of Hearts,  7 of Hearts,  8 of Hearts,  9 of Hearts,  10 of Hearts,  Jack of Hearts,  Queen of Hearts,  King of Hearts,  
Ace of Spades,  2 of Spades,  3 of Spades,  4 of Spades,  5 of Spades,  6 of Spades,  7 of Spades,  8 of Spades,  9 of Spades,  10 of Spades,  Jack of Spades,  Queen of Spades,  King of Spades,  

Shuffling cards....
Ace of Clubs,  2 of Clubs,  4 of Spades,  Jack of Diamonds,  Queen of Clubs,  7 of Diamonds,  10 of Clubs,  Queen of Hearts,  Queen of Diamonds,  Jack of Spades,  4 of Diamonds,  6 of Diamonds,  9 of Spades,  
9 of Hearts,  7 of Clubs,  2 of Spades,  6 of Spades,  Ace of Spades,  2 of Diamonds,  King of Diamonds,  10 of Diamonds,  3 of Spades,  8 of Diamonds,  5 of Hearts,  3 of Diamonds,  6 of Hearts,  
10 of Hearts,  Jack of Hearts,  9 of Diamonds,  King of Hearts,  Jack of Clubs,  King of Spades,  9 of Clubs,  4 of Clubs,  7 of Hearts,  King of Clubs,  Queen of Spades,  3 of Clubs,  8 of Spades,  
5 of Spades,  Ace of Diamonds,  4 of Hearts,  Ace of Hearts,  3 of Hearts,  8 of Hearts,  8 of Clubs,  2 of Hearts,  6 of Clubs,  5 of Clubs,  10 of Spades,  7 of Spades,  5 of Diamonds,  

Deal a card: Ace of Clubs, 
Cards remaining: 
Deal a card: 2 of Clubs, 
Cards remaining: 
Deal a card: 4 of Spades, 
Cards remaining: 
Deal a card: Jack of Diamonds, 
Cards remaining: 
Deal a card: Queen of Clubs, 
Cards remaining:
```

Here is my dealer.java

```
public class Dealer

   {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {  


     Deckofcards a;

     a = new Deckofcards();
     System.out.println(a);      // Prints what a new deck looks like     

     System.out.println("Shuffling cards....");            
     a.shuffle(1000);            // Shuffle deck of cards = "a"
     System.out.println(a);      // Prints deck after shuffling


    int cardsLeft = 51;

     card b;


     b = a.deal();
     System.out.println("Deal a card: " + b );
     System.out.println("Cards remaining: " +cardsLeft--);
     b = a.deal();
     System.out.println("Deal a card: " + b);
     System.out.println("Cards remaining: " +cardsLeft);
     b = a.deal();
     System.out.println("Deal a card: " + b);
     System.out.println("Cards remaining: " +cardsLeft);
     b = a.deal();
     System.out.println("Deal a card: " + b);
     System.out.println("Cards remaining: " +cardsLeft);
     b = a.deal();
     System.out.println("Deal a card: " + b);
     System.out.println("Cards remaining: " +cardsLeft);

      }


    }
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: added...maybe I am having the issue when trying to add it to my dealer...does it look right to you ???

Comment: Ok so I would set the number of cards that you have in your constructor then everytime you deal one you can decrement that number

Comment: I thought I set it with this,      public static final int NCARDS = 52;              public Deckofcards( )    // Constructor
      {
     deckOfCards = new card[ NCARDS ];

Comment: It looks like you're setting the array with that statement

Comment: ok let me take a look

Comment: I can't figure out how to get it to run properly. I would love it to run that way...just can't figure out were to put it to have it print in the proper spot. Or not mess up the rest of the FN code! CRAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your construction set cards left to 52. Then when you deal a card subtract that number by one

```
public card deal()
  {
  if ( currentCard < NCARDS  )
     {
        cardsLeft--;
        return ( deckOfCards[ currentCard++ ] );
     }
     else
     {
        System.out.println("Out of cards error");
        return (null);// Error;

     }  
  }
```

Comment: I just built it into my dealer, I put an int cardsLeft = 52. Then I subtracted everytime the card dealt. Not how I wanted it to go but unless someone else has an idea of how to build it into my deck .... Please

Comment: Are you not using the method "deal" in your deck class?

Comment: I can't seem to get it to function properly here is my method

Comment: public card deal()
      {
      if ( currentCard < NCARDS  )
      {
           return ( deckOfCards[ currentCard++ ] );
           
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("Out of cards error");
         return (null);// Error;
                 
      }  
      }
      
      
      public String toString()
      {
        
     String s = "";

     
     int k;
    
     k = 0;
     for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
     {
        for ( int j = 1; j <= 13; j++ )
     s += (deckOfCards[k++] + " ");
        s += "\n";
        
     
     }
    
     return ( s );
      }
        }

Comment: ok ive edited my answer so that when you deal a card the cards left goes down by one. If you have the cardsleft set to 52 it will correct everytime

Comment: then show me how youre printing it. i cant help you if you dont show me what is wrong

Comment: sorry I am just frustrated that I can't figure this out.

Comment: its all good. just add the code that prints it to your question and ill edit my answer

Comment: All my code is up there...if you are missing anything let me know.

Comment: youre only decrementing the first one